# undefined method `install_helpers' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x0000000139d85510> Did you mean? instance_values (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I got this error message while running `rails generate rspec:install` :

`` undefined method `install_helpers' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x0000000139d85510> Did you mean?  instance_values (NoMethodError) ``

My ruby version is 2.7.1
and rspec-rails gem is 5.0.2

I've trying with older rspec-rails version but I got the same troubles

thanks for help

Comment: According to https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Routing/RouteSet/install_helpers,
the `RouteSet#install_helpers` method was deprecated or moved after Rails 2.3.8. Can you show the relevant parts of your `config/routes.rb` please? This seems unrelated to RSpec.